# Entity Framework C# - Moving data from one database to another with similar structure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-express

I have two SQL Express databases, the first has alot of data in it, but we've build a new application that's going to run on a database that has similar table structures (added some columns, removed some, merged a few tables etc.). The client is the same and they want to use the old data in the new application.

So what I'm trying to do now is to move data (table by table) from the old DB, convert the entity (manually) from the old format to the new and then finally save that new entity in my new DB.

I'm using Entity Framework and the server is ASP.NET Web Api. I've created two seperate DbContext, one for the old DB and one for the new.
I'm able to get my data from the old DB, transform it, but then I run into my issue, I need the Identity columns to stay the same, so that I can maintain the relationships that exists in the old DB, but when I try to save the entity, EF tells me that I can't insert value in the Identity Column when Identity_Insert is OFF.

This is my actual Error message:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'AccessoryProfiles' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Here's my controller method that tries to migrate the data:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                var manager = new MigrationManager<AccessoryProfile>();

                var entities = manager.GetAll();


                foreach (var profile in entities)
                {
                    var newEntity = new Entities.Server.Accessories.AccessoryProfile
                    {
                        Id = profile.AccessoryProfileId,
                        Name = profile.Name,
                        CreatedDate = profile.CreatedDate,
                        LastModifiedDate = profile.LastModifiedDate,
                        DeletedDate = profile.DeletedDate
                    };

                    DataService.AccessoryProfile.Add(newEntity);
                }

                DataService.AccessoryProfile.Commit();

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Logger.Error(exc);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

`MigrationManager<T>` handles the old DB while `DataService` handles the new one.
I've tried setting [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] on the Id, but no luck. I've tried running this before my Commit():

`DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[AccessoryProfiles] ON");`

...but I still can't insert a value in the Identity Column.

How am I supposed to do this with Entity Framework?
Or if you know of a better way than using EF, I'm all ears.
Thanks!

Comment: You could just export the data in SQL Server to a `.csv`, convert it to an `.xls` and import it into the new db. Making changes to the schema in the `.xls` file shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Can't you just do this in SQL Queries? This approach for transferring data can be a serious headache. You could face a lot of other issues (such as this one), which are all easier to deal with in SQL. I'd suggest that you write queries such as insert into from select ...etc. Also remember to worry about the referential integrity between the Primary & Foreign keys .. Good luck.

Comment: Please check that you're running DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[AccessoryProfiles] ON"); against the receiving database context, rather than the sending one?

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this in code, rather than using a tool like those from RedGate, XSQL, DevArt, etc.?  These tools have methods built in them to address identity columns during data transfers.

Is this a process you have to repeat?

Comment: The reason I'm doing this in code is that it's the only enviroment I feel comfortable in and that I can loop through the tables and make the changes dynamically. I'm terrible at SQL-queries and would like to avoid them, but to export the DB into .xls and making the changes there sounds like a good option, except that I have around 12k items in a specific table, and making those changes have to be made dynamically. I' take a look at excel features as I'm not well versed in that either.

Comment: @WesleyLong After looking over the database, it's mainly renaming, adding and removing columns. I've used Redgate SQL Docs before and love it, but the pricing is a bit steep. I'm going to try making my changes in xls format and will reply after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are inserting an entire table, I would recommend using EntityFramework.BulkInsert. For a lot of records, ".Add" or ".AddRange" extensions are pretty slow.

Here is the description and speed advantages of bulkinsert:
https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/

[image]

You can also check out this thread for more info:
[Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)

When setting up your SqlBulkCopy, it allows you to overload it with different SqlBulkCopyOptions. I believe one of them is "KeepIdentity" which allows you to keep the source identity. I think that might be what you're looking for.

So when you set up your sqlbulkcopy object you might write something like this:

```
SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity| SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, null);
```

Also make sure you don't use the "CheckConstraints" option.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to make this work, I found the KeepIdentity setting and I don't get the key insert error. But I get "Model backing the "DbContext" has changed..." I tried new migration, but had no changes pending. I've deleted the database and recreated it using code first, but I get this error. I still run the same method as above. the difference is that I run ´DbContext.BulkInsert(entities, new BulkInsertOptions
            {
                SqlBulkCopyOptions = SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity
            });´ 
instead of ´DbContext.Add(entity);´ 
in my DataService. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, The error points to the DbContext of my new Database, not my old.

Comment: The error occured because when I installed BulkInsert it downgraded my Entity Framework to 6.0.0 for some reason. I updated EF and the error disappeared! And your solution worked smoothly, I got my whole table formatted and ready with correct Identity columns in my new DB. Thanks alot!